# How to add icons on the left side of an image?

Tags: html, css, image

I have the following code, and I know something is wrong but I can't tell what.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\.social-menu.css">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="C:3225888.jpg" alt="Nature" class="responsive">
  <!--Social Media-->
  <div class="conectt">
    <ul class="social-icons">
      <a href="http://www.instagram.com"><img style="width: 38px;" src='C:twitter.png'/></a>
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img style="width: 38px;" src='C:facebook.png'/></a>
      <a href="http://www.youtube.com"><img style="width: 38px;" src='C:youtube.png'/></a>
    </li>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I wanted to add images to the left side of the image. I know that something is wrong but I haven't been able to figure it out.
How do I add these icons on the left side of the image?

Comment: Do not use paths from your local computer, such as `C:facebook` ( which is missing a `/` or `\` anyway ) - use paths relative to your webserver. You **do** have a webserver running?

Comment: please add your code like CSS classes, images and try to recreate the problem so the community can understand it easily.

Comment: Use image placeholder so that we can see the state of the web page. For example: [image-placeholder](https://image-placeholder.com/social-icons/).

Comment: Can you post a sample image of what you want? or somwhere website you can refer to, where you have seen similar iamge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use fontawesome.
You have 2 possibilities :

First possibility : load fontawesome ressources from cdn link :

```
<!-- Use CDN-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Second possibility : download fontawesome files with this [link](https://fontawesome.com/v5.15/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself) and create folder in your project named font and put fontawesome files in :

```
<!--Internal file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/css/all.css">
```

This is all code using fontawesome with cdn :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Test</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\.social-menu.css">
    
        <!-- Use CDN-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    
        <!--Internal file-->
        <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/fontawesome-free-5.15.4-web/css/all.css">-->
      
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <style>
            #root{
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                align-items: center;
            }
    
            #root .conectt{
                margin: 25px;
            }
    
            .social-icons{
                list-style: none;
                padding-left: 0;
            }
    
            .social-icons li{
                padding: 10px;
            }
            .social-icons a{
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
            }
        </style>
    
        <div id="root">
            <div class="conectt">
                <ul class="social-icons">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square"></i></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <img src="C:3225888.jpg" class="nature" alt="Nature" class="responsive">
            <!--Social Media-->
        </div>
        
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Image : [image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You forgot to close-off the `ul` element by adding `</ul>` after the `</li>`;
2. You should also add the list in the HTML above the image. This will ensure that they appear before (and to the left of) the `img` element.
3. You should also add a CSS file to `float` the `div` element at the bottom to the `left`.

Answer (score 0):

Adopting this [CSS & Sprite sheet](https://michieltramper.com/how-to-add-social-media-icons-using-css3-and-image-sprites/) for brevity and convenience if you place both the image and the icon list (ul) within their own container you can `float` the icons to the left thus appearing befor ethe image even if they are physically declared after the `img` element.

```css
/* new css rules */
article{
  margin:2rem;
  padding:1rem;
}
article > ul {
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}




/* original css, modified slightly */
.social-media-icons {
    list-style: none;
    margin 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.social-media-icons li {
    display: block;
}
.social-media-icons a {/* edit: added full url */
    background-image: url(//leichim.github.io/retina-social-media-icons/assets/img/social-icons.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 58px;
    transition: all 350ms ease-out;
    width: 50px;
}
.social-media-icons a:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
.twitter {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
.facebook {
    background-position: -53px 0;
}
.dribbble {
    background-position: -106px 0;
}
.pinterest {
    background-position: -159px 0;
}
.deviantart {
    background-position: -212px 0;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <img src='//data.whicdn.com/images/45842479/original.jpg' />
  <ul class="social-media-icons">
      <li><a class="twitter" href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a class="facebook" href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a class="dribbble" href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a class="pinterest" href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a class="deviantart" href="#"></a></li>
  </ul>
</article>


<article>
  <img src='//e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/241/954/png-clipart-unicorn-cup-t-shirt-baby-unicorn-s-horse-purple-thumbnail.png' />
  <ul class="social-media-icons">
      <li><a class="twitter" href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a class="facebook" href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a class="dribbble" href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a class="pinterest" href="#"></a></li>
      <li><a class="deviantart" href="#"></a></li>
  </ul>
</article>
```